# razor nav issue when styled

Tags: navigation, asp.net-core-mvc

I 'm coding a nav bar in a ASP.NET Core MVC application. I ha a navigation working properly through all the pages. But when I add the style, the navigation doesn't work any more.
This is the navigation in a Partial view razor :

```html
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
                <a class="nav-item--regular nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" asp-page="/About">A Propos</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Pages" asp-action="NHPB">Accueil</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Pages" asp-action="PipeBand">A propos</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Pages" asp-action="Instruments">Contact</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Members">Les membres</a>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

The navigation work when style.

And this is the vue :

```html
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="subnav--sergent">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_SubNav"); }
            <div class="subnav--tri"><img class="px" src="~/images/1px.png" asp-append-version="true" /></div>
            <div class="subnav--rond">
                <button class="bouton bouton--rond" type="button">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_Adress"); }
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="section">
            <h2>Titre</h2>

            <p>Lorem, Bla, bla, bla.
            </p>
            <p>@DateTime.Now</p>
                        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="aside">
            <h1>Coucou</h1>
            <p>Je suis l'Aside !</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I really don't know why ? It was working fine when the partial view was style. It is just when I add the ****style in the view file that it doesn't work any more** ???

Thank for your help...

Comment: it is not clear , the link are not active or  the style isn't ?

Comment: The style work fine... But when I add the style on the page, the navigation menu doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Hullo,

I found out what was wrong. Some div are going on to my links... I have to find out which element(s) got on to them and fixed it with -Z-index...

And that work fine :

```css
   .subnav--sergent {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 17rem;
        background-color: $colorGraySergent;
        color: $colorGrayActu;
        padding: 0 3% 0 3%;
        margin-left: 2.7rem;
        min-height: 25rem;
        max-height: 25rem;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        top: 0;

        .subnav--main {
            margin-top: -15px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;

            li {
                padding-top: 0.5rem;

                a {
                    font-family: $article;
                    color: $colorWhite;
                    font-size: 1.3rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Rooky mistake...